# State management react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What would be the best way to maintain the state in this scenario; There is a react component which represents a filter. In the component there are state variables with initial values which can be changed by the user.

```
const [option, setOption] = useState(false)
```

Due to pagination, the component is rerendered causing the state variables to change back to their default values. What would be the best way to maintain the user options during the pagination (besides local storage)?

Comment: Does the pagination also use state? e.g. const [page, setPage] = useState(0) ?

Comment: A mere rerender would not cause the state to reset. You have to unmount and re-mount a component for this to happen. This sounds like either your state is in the wrong place or you have an issue with conditional rendering. Either way, we need to know more about your JSX and the structure of your components.